# SQL to standardize PostalCode data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with one column that stores Canadian Postal Codes.  Sometimes they're in the proper format H0H 0H0, and othertimes they're written like H0H0H0 or H0H-0H0.  I'm looking to be able to update all records to standardize the format as H0H 0H0 but I cannot figure out the SQL.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE PostalCodes SET PostalCode = LEFT(PostalCode, 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(PostalCode, 3 )
```

This assumes that the postal code field has already been trimmed on both the left and right sides.  It literally grabs the left 3 digits, places a space and then the right 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the following constraints hold:

- the field in question is always at least 6 characters in length.
- the first segment of the postal code is in columns 1-3 of the field
- the last segment is in the rightmost 3 columns of the field.
- There are zero or more extraneous characters located at column 4.

This should do the trick, for any number of characters in the field.:

```
update PostalCodes
set PostalCode = stuff( PostalCode , 4 , len(PostalCode) - 6 , ' ' )
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this — a case statement to look for all the different ways people have found to create junk postal codes and treat each according to its needs:

```
update PostalCodes
set PostalCode = case
                 when PostalCode like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][ -][0-9][A-Z][0-9]' then ...
                 when PostalCode like '![A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'    then ...
                 ...
                 else PostalCode 
                 end
```

A select statement like

select PostalCode,count(*)
   from  PostalCodes
   where PostalCode not like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]'
   group by PostalCode
   order by 2 desc

should show you the junk data.